# Python loop not functioning as intended when reading in lines

Tags: python, xml, find

I am attempting to parse an XML file and remove unnecessary tags from the line. My loop is getting caught up and won't apply second `if` statement on the  tag and I am unsure why.. I've been staring at this for over an hour and testing new methods, but I keep getting the error `ParseError: mismatched tag:`. From debugging, I can tell the its not even going into the second if statement, but the logic to me seems like it should. I know I am missing something small here, but can't figure it out... Any ideas?

**Loop**

```
with open('test.xml') as inXML, open(outputFilename, 'w') as outXML:
    outXML.write('<root>\n')
    for line in inXML.readlines():
        if (line.find("<sub>")):
            newline = line.replace("<sub>", "")
            newLine = newline.replace("</sub", "")
        elif (line.find("<sup>")):
            newline = line.replace("<sup>", "")
            newLine = newline.replace("</sup", "")

        outXML.write(re.sub('&[a-zA-Z]+;',anglicise,newLine))
    outXML.write('\n</root>')
```

**XML to test**

```
<pub>
    <ID>5010</ID>
    <title>Model-Checking for L<sub>2</sub</title>
    <year>1997</year>
    <booktitle>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</booktitle>
    <pages></pages>
    <authors>
        <author>Helmut Seidl</author>
    </authors>
</pub>
<pub>
    <ID>71035</ID>
    <title>S_2p \subseteq ZPP<sup>NP</sup</title>
    <year>2001</year>
    <booktitle>Electronic Colloquium on Computational Complexity (ECCC)</booktitle>
    <pages></pages>
    <authors>
        <author>Jin-yi Cai</author>
    </authors>
</pub>
```

Comment: Use a xml-parser, like `ElementTree` to parse xml.

Comment: Don't use string methods to try to parse XML... use an XML parser. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: The input is not valid XML, so using an XML parser won't work.

Comment: I am using ETree as well lower in my code (I am very new to python), but how do I pull out bad tags with Etree?

Comment: @BrenBarn Correct, however, my teacher has assigned us a broken XML file to parse through

Comment: Also, there's no need to check `if <substring> in <string>` before using `<string>.replace(<substring>, <replacements>)`, if `substring` isn't there, it won't throw an error. Also, your logic here is off since if both of your conditions fail, it will write whatever `newLine` had *previously*

Comment: It is not a great idea to have variables called `newline` and `newLine`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's what I was thinking, but aren't python strings immutable, so I have to create a newstring to save the oldstring into? Versus saving the changed string back onto itself?

Comment: @BrenBarn good catch!

Comment: @douglasrcjames yeah, sure, but you don't need the `if` and `elif` conditions, is all I'm saying.  Indeed, you could just chain your method calls into one method-cascade: `line = line.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)...` Of course, sometimes it's just more readable to do `line = line.replace(...); line = line.replace(...)...` on seperate lines...

Comment: Yeah, you don't actually need *three seperate names*: `line, newline, and newLine`. That's just confusing. You can just keep reassigning to `line`.

Comment: Yes, I agreee it looks silly, but my understanding was `line = line.replace(...)` does not work, because you need to make a new string to save the changed string into

Comment: Just tried this, giving me the same error :/
`for line in inXML.readlines():
        line = line.replace("<sub>", "").replace("</sub>", "").replace("<sup>", "").replace("</sup>", "")
        outXML.write(re.sub('&[a-zA-Z]+;',anglicise,line))`

Comment: @douglasrcjames: That is different from your original code because your original code has `</sup` and `</sub` (without final `>`), not `</sup>` and `</sub>`.

Comment: @BrenBarn ugh sorry, I need to take a break, been at this too long. Thanks tho guys, that worked :)

Comment: **anglicise** is undefined -- can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga & @BrenBarn, solution was stacking .replace() statements on one line iteration as follows:

```
with open('test.xml') as inXML, open(outputFilename, 'w') as outXML:
    outXML.write('<root>\n')
    for line in inXML.readlines():
        line = line.replace("<sub>", "").replace("</sub", "").replace("<sup>", "").replace("</sup", "")
        outXML.write(re.sub('&[a-zA-Z]+;',anglicise,line))
    outXML.write('\n</root>')
```